# CommentDeleter ColorMatcher™

Tags: script, comments

### About

Makes the "Delete" button on comments match the other comment links.

Created in response to [this post on Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379776/8828658).

#### Download

Get it on [GitHub](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/CommentDeleter-ColorMatcher), or from here:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         CommentDeleter ColorMatcher™
// @description     Make the comment Delete link match the other links on the comment
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include  https://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include  https://*superuser.com/*
// @include  https://*serverfault.com/*
// @include  https://*stackapps.com/*
// @include  https://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include  https://*stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

function with_jquery(f) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

with_jquery(function(){
  StackExchange.ready(function(){
    $(".comment-delete").removeClass("fc-red-600");
  });
});
```

#### Platform

Tested in GreaseMonkey.

### Code

Made with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)!

Report [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s on [GitHub](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/CommentDeleter-ColorMatcher).